In Django + REST Framework, what is the right way to get prefetched data in complex serializers?
We are making a web app quite similar to a forum (in the concept). Users can post messages in threads which are organized in nested categories which belong to a project. A project is a group of users and their content / activity inside it.
We are using Django + DRF for the backend and Vue for the frontend.
I take over on the backend and I installed debug toolbar. I realize that our backend is a mess that makes a lot of queries so I'm trying to manage that. I found lot of tutorials for prefetch_related and select_related on easy examples but in my case I'm struggling to get this to work.
What I would do for now: get the current project and its last 12 most recently active threads with their last message in one request.
Here are my models:
# projects/models.py

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True,
        upload_to=project_directory_path,
        max_length=500,
        verbose_name=_("Project image"),
        validators=[validate_file_extension]) # not working. Bug ?
    image_token = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name=_('image token'))
    preferences = models.TextField(blank=True,verbose_name=_('Preferences'))

    # ... some other methods ....

# messaging/models.py

class Category(models.Model):

    STATUS = [
        ('published', _('Published')),
        ('archived', _('Archived')),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=_('Title'))
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Description'))
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Project'), related_name="messaging_categories")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=_('Status'), choices=STATUS, default='published')
    color = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=6, verbose_name=_('Color'))
    rank = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Rank"), default=0)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="child_categories")

    # ... some other methods ....


class Thread(models.Model):

    STATUS = [
        ('published', _('Published')),
        ('archived', _('Archived')),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=_('Title'))
    synthesis = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Synthesis'))
    synthesis_date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Synthesis update date'))
    synthesis_user_update = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name=_('Synthesis update user'))
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('Update date'))
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Category'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=_('Status'), choices=STATUS, default='published')
    messages_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Update messages date'))
    messages_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dates = models.ManyToManyField(Date, blank=True, null=True, related_name='threads')
    polls = models.ManyToManyField(Poll, blank=True, null=True, related_name='threads')
    modules = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Modules'))

class ThreadAccess(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User'))
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Thread'))
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('Date'))

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields= ['user','thread'], name='unique_user_access'),
            ]

class Message(models.Model):

    STATUS = [
        ('draft', _('draft')),
        ('sent', _('sent')),
    ]

    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Message'))
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Thread'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=_('Status'), choices=STATUS, default='draft')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Date'))
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('Update date'))
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Post date'))
    edit_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Edit date'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User'))
    medias = models.ManyToManyField(Media, blank=True)

    # ... some other methods ....


Here is my view (I try to store the last threads in the initial method because it's the only way I found not to call that query many times):
# projects/views.py

class ProjectsViewSet(BaseProjectsViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    action_permission_classes = {
        'update': [ProjectAdminPermission],
        'destroy': [ProjectAdminPermission]
    }

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        self.permissions = {}

        if user and user.is_superuser:
            self.permissions['superuser'] = list(
       Permission.objects.filter(content_type__model='project').values_list("codename", flat=True)
            )
        else:

            permissions = UserObjectPermission.objects.select_related('permissions').filter(
                user=user, 
                content_type__model='project',
            ).values('object_pk', 'permission__codename')

            for permission in permissions:

                pk = int(permission['object_pk'])
                codename = permission['permission__codename']

                if pk in self.permissions:
                    self.permissions[pk].add(codename)
                else:
                    self.permissions[pk] = {codename}

        if 'last_threads' in self.request.GET.get("extra_fields", "").split(","):
            self.last_threads = self.get_last_threads()
        return super().initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_last_threads(self):
        queryset = Thread.objects.filter(
            category__project=self.get_object(),
            category__status="published",
            messages_number__gt=0,
            status="published").select_related('category').prefetch_related('message_set', 'category__child_categories')
        return queryset
        

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context["extra_fields"] = self.request.GET.get("extra_fields", "").split(",")
        context["permissions"] = self.permissions
        if 'last_threads' in self.request.GET.get("extra_fields", "").split(","):
            context["last_threads"] = self.last_threads
        return context

    # ... some other methods ....


Here are my serializers:
# projects/serializer.py

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
    permissions = serializers.SerializerMethodField('project_permissions')
    users = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_users')
    last_threads = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_last_threads')
    last_medias = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_last_medias')
    last_events = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_last_events')
    last_polls = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_last_polls')
    posts = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_posts')
    subscriptions = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_subscriptions')
    thumbnail = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_thumbnail')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'slug', 'pk', 'permissions', 'users', 'image', 'thumbnail', 'preferences', 'last_threads', 'last_medias', 'last_events', 'last_polls', 'posts', 'subscriptions']
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        read_only_fields = ['pk', 'slug', 'permissions', 'users', 'thumbnail', 'last_threads', 'last_medias', 'last_events', 'last_polls', 'posts', 'subscriptions']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        extra_fields = self.context.get("extra_fields", None) or []
        EXTRAS = [ 'last_threads', 'last_medias', 'last_events', 'last_polls', 'posts', 'users', 'subscriptions']
        for extra in EXTRAS:
            if extra not in extra_fields:
                del self.fields[extra]

     def get_last_threads(self, obj):
        if 'last_threads' in self.context: 
            threads = self.context['last_threads']
        else : 
            threads = []
        serializer = ThreadSerializer(threads, many=True, context={'request': self.context.get("request"),'project': obj, 'user': self.get_current_user()})
        return serializer.data


    # ... some other methods ....

# messaging/serializer.py

class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    synthesis_user_update = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    unread_messages_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_unread_messages_number')
    last_message = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    category = CategorySerializer(many=False)
    dates = SimpleDateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = [
            'pk', 'title', 'category', 'status', 'synthesis', 
            'update', 'messages_update', 'messages_number', 'modules'
            ]
        lookup_field = 'pk'
        read_only_fields = [
            'pk', 'category', 
            'update', 'messages_update', 'messages_number',
            ]
    
    def get_unread_messages_number(self, obj):
        return obj.get_unread_messages_number(self.context.get("user"))

    def get_last_message(self, obj):   
        # Here it is : I don't know how to properly get a Message object properly...


The old code was:
def get_last_message(self, obj):  
    return MessageSerializer(obj.get_last_message(), many=False, context={'request': self.context.get("request"), 'thread_access_date':None, 'hello': 'coucou'}).data

I was messing around with this:
def get_last_message(self, obj):
        # this is for test purpose, and doesn't add a query
        for thread in self.instance:
            for message in thread.message_set.all():
                print(message.text)
                print()
        # End of the test
        thread = self.instance.filter(thread_pk=obj.pk, status='sent').last()
        return MessageSerializer(thread, many=False, context={'request': self.context.get("request"), 'thread_access_date':None}).data

But it doesn't work or it makes a lot of queries to DB.
How to request the project and its threads with their last message in the same call?
